# iOs7 tab bar changes

Tags: ios, ios7, xib, uitabbar, tabbarcontroller

At ios 6.1 and previous I have like this:

[image: ios6]

I  need to add support to iOS 7 ( and keep 5.1, 6.0, 6.1) but at iOS 7 it look like this:

[image: ios7]

At xib file my settings at tab bar:

[image: tab bar]

At tab controller:

[image: tab controller]

What to change, where to have a similar look as previous versions?

Comment: Don't know how to do that in IB, but if you don't find a good answer just subclass. It's super easy and you're in full control.

Comment: in worse scenario that I  need to do

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color of the highlighted icons by setting the `tintColor` of the `tabBar`. Like so:

```
// Example UITabBarController
UITabBarController *tabVC = [UITabBarController alloc] init];

tabVC.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Comment: I have changed in IB but that changed the text color too, upvoted for effort

Answer (score 1):

Based on Eric answer I have solved the problem like this:

[image]

Observe: the Translucient is unchecked!

And looks like this:

[image]

Observe: The text color is yellow instead of white.

Answer (score 1):

Try This its Working....

in Didfinishlaunching

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
   UITabBarItem *tabBarItem5 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];
```

**Set your Selected and Unselected TabImage Here..**.

```
     [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon-selected-_Home-ipad.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon_Home-ipad.png"]];

    [tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon-selected-_Products-ipad.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon_Products-ipad.png"]];

    [tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon-selected-_Manuf.-Facili-ipad.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon_Manuf.-Facili-ipad.png"]];

    [tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon-selected-_R-n-D-ipad.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon_R-n-D-ipad.png"]];

    [tabBarItem5 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon-selected-_contact-Us-ipad.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_icon_contact-Us-ipad.png"]];
```

**Note:-**
Set all Tabs Selected image Dynamically in Tabbaritem in Property Window

Answer (score 0):

You can set your tab bar to the old style like this:

> `self.tabBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;`

Comment: @user529543 No, it's not. UIBarStyleBlackOpaque and UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent are deprecated. UIBarStyleBlackOpaque is replaced by UIBarStyleBlack and UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent is replaced by UIBarStyleBlack with the translucent property set to YES.